# How to apply filter to Django rest-framework serializer field?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Say I have three models like these:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    img = models.ForeignKey('Image')


class Image(models.Model):
    deleted = models.BooleanField()
    url = models.URLField()
    msg = models.ForeignKey('Message')

class Tag(models.Model):
    deleted = models.BooleanField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    msg = models.ForeignKey('Message')
```

When serializing `Message`, I need its `tag`s and `url`s are not deleted which means `deleted` field is `False`. I hope a customized SlugField should work like this:

```
class ValidSlugField(serializers.SlugRelatedField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ValidSlugField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ValidSlugField, self).get_queryset().filter(deleted=False)
```

But `get_queryset` raised an error. Is it possible to make a 'generic validated' field like this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54303205/how-to-apply-filter-to-django-rest-framework-serializer-field it may be related to what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you had created 3 models to it maybe you can do something like this if fit for you.

1. Creating only one model which is include all fields.
2. Creating a custom serializer which is:

   ```
   class MessageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
       #all fields are here
   ```
3. With this link you can validate Message. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation

   ```
   class MessageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
       #all fields are here
       def validate(self,data):
           deleted = data.get('deleted')
           text = data.get('text')    
           img = data.get('img')
           if : #the shape of text or img for deleted is false
                data['deleted'] = false 
                return data
           return data #the shape of text or img for deleted is true
       def save(self):
             #use validated_data here
   ```
4. After you can use `save()` method to use validated data like
    `deleted = self.validated_data['deleted']`

Comment: Actually I have quite a lot models, all of them have a field to indicate whether the instance is marked invalid or expired. So every time I try to query and serialize an instance, I hope its foreign key fields are valid. This is not about validation anyway.